# What's the proper way to extract part of the file to another file saving version history in Perforce?

Tags: version-control, perforce

First of all I would like to say that I've read this question

[What's the proper way to refactor a single file into multiple files and maintain version history in Perforce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023021/whats-the-proper-way-to-refactor-a-single-file-into-multiple-files-and-maintain)

But it is still unclear for me, how to do the same but for slightly different case:

Let's say that you've found one `ClassA.cs` file with two c# classes `ClassA` and `ClassB` defined. So you want to place ClassB to separate file. You creating new file and ctrl-x'ing `ClassB` declaration to this file. **How to tell perforce to maintain history for this file?** I was playing with `p4 integrate` command, but the result of it's work isn't clear for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this:

```
p4 integ ClassA.cs ClassB.cs
p4 edit ClassA.cs ClassB.cs
```

The 'integ' clones ClassA.cs into a local, read-only copy named ClassB.cs. The 'edit' makes the local ClassA.cs and ClassB.cs files writable so you can edit them.

After editing these files to separate the ClassA and ClassB code, submit them:

```
p4 submit
```

Now you can use:

```
p4 filelog -i ClassB.cs
```

to see the new file's history, including its history as ClassA.cs.